# Efficiency with java strings

Tags: java, android

When we extend DefaultHandler, we usually override the characters function.

I was wondering which would be a more efficient way to extract the String supplied...

---

1. **Would it be using a for loop and a StringBuilder?**

   ```
   @Override
   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length); 
       for(int i=start; i<start+length; i++)
           sb.append(ch[i]);
       String values = sb.toString();
   }
   ```
2. **Would it be using a simple substring?**

   ```
   @Override
   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
       String values = (new String(ch)).substring(start, start + length);
   }
   ```
3. **Is there another approach?**

Comment: **Note** that the `#characters(char[] ch, int, int)` method *may* be called several times in a row and you should **append** character data in a `StringBuilder` class member and not process it until you hit the relevant `#endElement(String,String,String)` call. Appending chunks of characters should be done by calling `StringBuilder#append(char[], int, int)`.

Comment: @Jens You are correct! I have been working a lot with feeds and I noticed this behavior. The problem is that it will be too messy to use a StringBuilder to append (especially for the part of maintaining reference). I prefer to use string concatenation in this case.

Comment: If you are implementing `ContentHandler`s manually you should probably consider using some sort of framework - even a simple one like the built in [android.sax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10768314/967142) would probably simply things for you.

Comment: I have worked on a small utility that creates the handlers. I intend to further work on it but not having time though. http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/sax-class-generator-v10.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) that takes a char[] and a range, if that is what you are looking for:

```
new String(ch, start, length);
```

Comment: Oh and needless to say, it will perform better than any.

Answer (score 0):

String Class has new constructor which can fulfil your requirements as follows

```
1) new String(char[] value)

2) new String(char[] value, int StartIndex, int numberOfCharacter)
```